# Granting select on syscat.schemata - DB2

Tags: permissions, schema, db2, users, db2-luw

I was wondering if it is safe to grant select rights to syscat.schemata to users on a DB2 database? What could go "wrong"?

Some tool like DataGrip and DBeaver cannot load connection schemas because of this missing rights.
Others tools like AQT or SquirrelSQL load schemas that they see with not problem.

I am not really at home in DB2 environment.

Comment: @mustaccio It has come to my attention that grants were removed because of PCI DSS hardening. Please post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select privileges on all `SYSCAT` objects are granted by default to the `PUBLIC` pseudo-group (unless the database is created as "restrictive"), so you shouldn't have ended up with users not being able to access `syscat.schemata` unless you or someone before you chose to actively prevent that.

> What could go "wrong"?

Users will be able to discover what schemas exist in your database. Obviously this doesn't give them any extra privileges to see or access in any way objects in those schemas. In other words, being able to read `syscat.schemata` is pretty harmless.